# Need to create shell script that accepts parameters

Tags: linux

Shell script to accept two parameters , i had a script file named createproject.sh

```
     #!/bin/bash
     echo "Project Name :$1 "
     echo "Group Id : $2 "
     mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=$2 -DartifactId=$1 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-      archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

     cd $1
     mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

and i had to execute this by command

```
  sh createproject.sh projectname com.test.app
```

where projectname and com.test.app are requires project name and package structure but i need to do something like

```
 sh createproject.sh -P projectname and -G com.test.app
```

so that the user can be informed as -P : Project Name and -G : group Id .Please let me know the changes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "the $1 eats a $2 every time there is a $3"
echo "bye:-)"
```

[source - wikia](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script)

Answer (score 2):

Check the Bash's documentation about [Positional Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters)...

> A positional parameter is a parameter denoted by one or more digits, other than the single digit 0. Positional parameters are assigned from the shell’s arguments when it is invoked, and may be reassigned using the set builtin command. Positional parameter N may be referenced as ${N}, or as $N when N consists of a single digit. Positional parameters may not be assigned to with assignment statements. The set and shift builtins are used to set and unset them (see Shell Builtin Commands). The positional parameters are temporarily replaced when a shell function is executed (see Shell Functions).
>
> When a positional parameter consisting of more than a single digit is expanded, it must be enclosed in braces.